# Add body class to both Node add and Node Edit Page

Tags: nodes, theming

I want to add a Body class to my Node Add pages and my Node Edit Pages.

How can I do this?

I know that I need use the following in `template.php` to add a class to Node Edit:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
     if (arg(0)=='node' && arg(2)=='edit') {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-edit-page';
    }
}
```

But how can I modify the code to work with node add?

Note: Node Add is when you create a node (e.g. yousite.com/node/add/page).

Node Edit is when you edit an existing page  (e.g. yousite.com/node/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ((arg(0)=='node' && arg(2)=='edit') || (arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add')) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-edit-page';
  }
}
```